# If I submit this "first draft code" instead of a spec, will the programmer like it or hate it?

Tags: ms-access, specifications

I am a factory employee who's done just a little programming.  I want to suggest that our computer shift reports do a couple calculations for us so I don't have to punch them into a calculator several times a day.  Rather than just saying "I would like the computer to take the net net weight and tare weight I entered elsewhere and tell me the gross weight", I would like to submit some code or pseudocode with my suggestion:

```
function calculategross () {
    int gross = fldshf_skidnet + fldshf_tare;  
    //use fldshf_skidnet, not fldshf_net in case of multiple rolls per skid.
    }
```

Since I know exactly which calculations I need done and which variables are available in the database table, pseudocode could save the application programmer a lot of thought.  It should make my suggestion look more viable as well, and writing new code is just fun.  But a real programmer might rather have a detailed spec or something without my opinion on the technical features.  If a manager asked you to code something and submitted some non-compiling "code", would you say "hey, good roadmap" or "geez, get a clue"?

Background: The shift report is a tabbed form view of a database table, made in Alpha V5.  So you have a front end that looks somewhat like the first result [here](http://images.google.com/images?hl=en&safe=off&gbv=2&biw=800&bih=440&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=user+control+tab+in+form&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=), and if you hit F8 you are looking at the underlying table in the database.  (This is how I know all the variable names.)  My calculator page would be on its own tab.  Some of the data it uses will be user-entered in other tabs, some on the page itself.

Here's some of the "first draft code" I'm considering.  The interface stuff that I'm shakier on is near the top, some of the calculator functions are at the bottom.

```
Button GetDataButton = new Button();
GetDataButton.onclick() = UpdateAllUneditedVariables() {
    //Populate all fields on this tab with data entered elsewhere 
    //Don't update fields the user changed on this page.
    //I didn't actually write this function, I'm just describing it.
    }

Button CalculateAll = new Button();
CalculateAll.onclick() {
    FillEmptyFieldsWithDefaultValues();
    CallAllCalculatorFunctions();
    DisplayAllCalculationResults();
    }

sub CallAllCalculatorFunctions() {
    CalculateGross();
    CalculateAverage();
    CalculateNetPoundsPerHour();
    //I feel like this is a non-programmer way to structure this...
    }


//Here's a couple of the mathier functions -- not that hard, but complicated 
//enough that I'd rather not have the programmer have to think through them.

function SkidsPerJob () {
    //How many skids must we divide this job into based on weight limits?
    int max_by_weight = ceil (fldshf_total_lbs / max_lbs_skid);

    //How many based on height limits?
    float total_height = fldshf_gauge * fldshf_total_sheets;
    int max_by_height = ceil(total_height / max_height / stacks_per_skid);

    int total_skids = max (max_by_weight, max_by_height);
    }

function CalculateNetPoundsPerHour () {
    int netpph = sheet_weight / sheet_length * feet_per_minute * 12 * 60;
    if (number_of_webs > 1) {netpph *= number_of_webs;
    }
```

If you don't think this is good, would you recommend just refreshing my coding ability by brushing up on Microsoft Access forms?  (I have made them before, with dropdowns and everything, just not recently.)  Get an editor from Scriptlance to fix naming conventions and coding errors?  Or should I just concentrate on the look of the page and describing the functions I need and not try to design it myself?

Comment: if you find any of the answers useful please consider upvoting them.

Comment: @Simon - "Vote Up requires 15 reputation," it told me when I clicked on the upvote.  So I thought, "Since I can't upvote the answers I like, I will comment on how they helped me -- that makes people feel good."  And then once I was sure all the discussion was done I was going to accept one of the answers -- hopefully it doesn't take 15 reputation to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the agile world you would tend to avoid trying to spec everything up front, accepting that this is nigh on impossible, and instead allow the design to evolve through continual prototyping and interaction with the developer (see [Scrum](http://www.scrumalliance.org/learn_about_scrum) or [DSDM](http://www.dsdm.org/) for example).

My advice is to focus on the business requirements and allow the developer to decide exactly how best to implement them, that's his job and he will know how to do it better than you. Doubtless he will also have things like coding standards and existing libraries of code he may want to re-use. You should be primarily concerned with working closely with him to ensure that he understands your requirements (I would advise you to break them up into small, discrete 'chunks') so that what he produces addresses your needs and there are no surprises come delivery day.

Comment: From your answer I'm taking the importance of focusing on working with the programmer.  I can tell I wish I could do it all myself, but that won't get it done.  

For chunking, instead of presenting a big block of code I'll do like so:  
-page 1: Draw up how I want the form to look  
-page 2: Left half of form on the left side of the page, notes/code for each separate calculator on the right side of the page.  
-page 3: Same thing for the other half of the form.  
I hope Markdown accepts my double spaces as line breaks or else this comment's gonna look terrible again.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it reminded me that it's not my job to make a workable program.  The programmer has skills and utilities I don't have and my suggestion needed to be aimed at communicating to him, not at building the application itself.  Here's the suggestion as I turned it in (PDF), if anyone wants to see. https://sites.google.com/site/fireslinger/calculator-page/CalculatorPageCOMBINEDFINAL.pdf?attredirects=0&d=1

Answer (score 2):

When writing a specification, you have to express what you want in a language that both you and the developer understands. I think it is a good idea to make use of your programming experience and express the *[business logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic)* in a programming-like language. I wouldn't bother with coding errors or naming conventions: It is more important that you get the naming right (from a [domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) perspective) than syntactical correctness.

Don't spend too much time on this, though. Focus on the *things that are unique to your domain*.

Comment: edit: whoa, clicking enter hits submit?  Shades of Facebook.  

So if I want a button that you click to display all the results of the calculators, there's no business logic to that -- that's just application logic, and up to the programmer's discretion.  When he chooses to update the variables in the fields is application logic too.  What I need to specify very carefully is stuff like "If the job is being run two sheets at a time, the net weight calculation should be doubled."  That's the stuff that comes out of the specifics of my job that a programmer shouldn't have to guess at.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said (Anders Lindahl & Simon), you should be focusing on making sure the programmer understands your business requirements.

As a progammer, I'd rather see the spec as a screeen diagram, with descriptions of *what* each button (or other active control) does, than screen-creation pseudocode. However, I see nothing wrong with specifying the *calculations* in pseudocode, particularly if they're tricky. If the order of operations is critical (either from a user perspecitve or a "this value depends on that calculation" one), I'd also welcome *high-level* English-like pseudocode to specify the crucial bits.